# Can Ruby global variables be inherited?

Tags: ruby

If I call a ruby object like this

```
 def classA
     @myvar = "A"
 end

 def classB < classA
     puts @myvar
 end
```

In ruby, is it possible to print and access @myvar?

Comment: there are alot of things wrong with that, those aren't class definitions to begin with

Comment: You are not calling anything here except `puts`. There is no Ruby object here except `"A"`, which you are in no sense calling. `@myvar` is not a global variable. `def` are not class definitions. You can't inherit methods. Please read a Ruby tutorial (and pay close attention to terminology).

Comment: There is literally not a single word in this entire question that even remotely makes any sense at all. How is this question 12 hours old and not yet deleted?

Answer (score 0):

First, ruby classes are defined with the `class` keyword.
`def` is for methods.
Also, ruby class names should always start with a capital letter.

`@myvar` isn't a global variable.
In ruby you create global variables using a dollar sign: `$myvar`.
The at sign is giving you an instance variable.
Instance variables are available to all methods in the class in which they are defined, but they need to be initialized by a method.
If you want a variable that doesn't need to be initialized inside a method, you can also use a class variable, like this `@@myar`.
Only one copy of `@@myvar` will exist, shared among all instances of your class, and it will be inherited by child classes.

If you want to access the variable from outside your class, you will need a getter method that gives you access to the variable.
An example is as follows

```
class ClassA
  @@myvar = "A"
end

class ClassB < ClassA
  def myvar
    @@myvar
  end
end

b = ClassB.new
puts b.myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

You write a class like this

```
class A 

end

class B 

end
```

If you are talking about global variables, something like this would be good enough

```
class A
  $var = 1
end
```

Now this $var is accessible everywhere .. it travels through the walls! So you can access in `class B` as well.